# Is there a difference between the CyanogenMod 11S Rom (for OnePlus One) and regular CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod

How does the CyanogenMod 11S Rom on the forthcoming OnePlus One smartphone differ (if at all) from regular versions or nightlies of CyanogenMod that can be downloaded and installed on other Smartphones ?

Would this be another unique selling point (from a software perspective) for this particular handset?

[OnePlus](http://oneplus.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AndroidPit has an article that outlines the major differences.

http://www.androidpit.com/cyanogenmod-11-vs-cyanogenmod-11s-the-main-differences

- Google Apps, no root
- Extra Themes and Wallpapers
- Display activation via tapping
- Optional on-screen buttons
- Screen calibration and adaptive lighting
- Camera and Gallery App
- Boot Animation
- AudioFX instead of DPS Manager

Other than this, CyanogenMod 11S is natively tested on the OnePlus One and contains the best possible drivers for the phone. Essentially, it is optimised to run on the OnePlus One..